# How i can filter one column by multiple values (strict filter)?

Tags: mysql, sql

After many attempts I have not been able to solve this, so I have decided to share it with you to see if you can help me.

I have created an advanced product search, but i can't filter the products according to the selected categories, i explain:

I have two tables, products and products_categories.

```
+------------------+
|     Prodcuts     |
+-------+----------+
| pr_id | pr_title |
+-------+----------+
| 1     | Iphone   |
+-------+----------+
| 2     | Samsung  |
+-------+----------+
| 3     | Xiaomi   |
+-------+----------+
```

```
+--------------------------+
|    Products Categories   |
+------------+-------------+
| ct_product | ct_category |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | 5           |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | 7           |
+------------+-------------+
| 2          | 8           |
+------------+-------------+
```

I want to filter only the products have the selected categories, for example, my mysql query is:

```
SELECT * products WHERE products.pr_id IN (SELECT ct_product FROM products_categories WHERE ct_category IN (5, 8, 7)
```

The result of this query is Iphone and Samsung.

But what i want is that if any product does not have the 3 categories selected that does not show anything, because product id 1 does not have category id 8 and vice versa.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `distinct count()`

```
SELECT * products WHERE products.pr_id IN(
select ct_product
from products_categories
where  ct_category IN (5, 8, 7)
group by ct_product
having count(distinct ct_category)=3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `inner join`:

```
SELECT * products p
INNER JOIN products_categories pc on pc.ct_product = p.pr_id
WHERE pc.ct_category IN (5, 8, 7)
```